# Tkinter and PIL: Changing Displayed Image via OptionMenu selection

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

a little new to Tkinter and PIL, trying to setup a GUI that switches the displayed image based on what selection was made in the OptionMenu. The path updates fine, however the image does not. Any remedies?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

def changeimage():
    path.set(cwd + '/img/' + imageVar.get() + '.png')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path.get()))
    panel.configure(image = img)

window = Tk()
window.configure(background='grey')

imageVar = StringVar(window)
images = {'image1', 'image2', 'image3'}
imageVar.set('image1')

cwd = os.getcwd()

imageSelectMenu = OptionMenu(window, imageVar, *images)
imageSelectMenu.pack()

path = StringVar(window)
path.set(cwd + '/img/' + imageVar.get() + '.png')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path.get()))

panel = Label(window, image = img)
panel.pack()

imageVar.trace('w', changeimage)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have absolutely no callbacks to set `img` after initially running the first time

Comment: added a callback, image changes to blank canvas instead of image I intend

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common bug. In tkinter, you must keep a reference to the image object or it gets garbage collected.

```
def changeimage():
    path.set(cwd + '/img/' + imageVar.get() + '.png')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path.get()))
    panel.configure(image = img)
    panel.img = img # keep a reference
```